# Application context configuration for json parsing in jersey

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, java-ee-7

I'm developing web service using jax-rs. I have configured `Application` class. It works fine on default xml format. there is no web.xml file. I want to enable json format support. I have found some solution using web.xml. I want to know if there is any way to enable json format support using jersey-json library **without using web.xml**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jackson as your JSON serializer? If so, add it in your application class

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();

    //add all your services

    classes.add(JacksonFeature.class);
    return classes;
}
```

And annotate your rest endpoints (Produces, Consumes) with MediaType.APPLICATOIN_JSON wherever you need them. It should work without need of any web.xml

Comment: Which package contains JacksonFeature class ?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson. If you have an Application Server like glassfish it is contained automatically.